# Combinations and maintainance of Rudraksha?

Tags: worship, vedic-rituals, rudraksha

I wanted to know , if the scriptures and purana allow a person to wear any number of Rudraksha in any , odd or even parity , for combined effect without creating any bad consequence . Also , what are the authentictic ways to maintain a Rudraksha daily and monthly? Which books can be referred to for getting authentic answers?(please mention the sources for the answers). Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of care needed for an individual Rudraksha depends on the quality of the bead. A+ Grade Rudraksha beads are considered to be the most low maintenance beads because they have spent the required time in nature and are fully grown and nourished.

Here are some of the most important care tips that will guarantee that your Rudraksha remains in good health for the longest period of time:

**Oiling the Rudraksha Bead:** It is fair to say that oil (Preferably Rudraksha seed oil or Almond oil) is Rudraksha’s best friend. The expert tip is to use a soft brush to apply oil to your Rudraksha.

**Keep your Rudraksha away from chemicals** found in soap, hand wash, sanitizers, deodorant, or other beauty products that might cause your Rudraksha bead to dry and gradually lose color. The best practice is to remove your Rudraksha bead during the application of these products.

**Do not use too much water on your Rudraksha.** If your Rudraksha does come into contact with water, please air dry your Rudraksha or use cotton cloth to dry your Rudraksha bead. Apply oil to the Rudraksha after it is dried to prevent cracks.

**Do not soak Rudraksha in Ghee or milk**. This is a false and baseless practice and is certain to cause fungus to develop on your Rudraksha bead. During energizing, the Rudraksha is washed with Panchamrit, but Nepa Rudraksha ensures that proper precautions are taken before and after the ceremony to maintain the quality and durability of your Rudraksha bead. Hence, it is not advisable for customers to practice this without proper knowledge.

[The Source for the answer.](https://nepalirudraksha.com/blogs/blog/rudraksha-care)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).